# Regex issue with finding words partially

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

I have a regex that's working for some words but not all:

```
str.scan(/typeaheadResult\(\{\"Q\":("\w+\s?\w+\s?\w+\s?\w+"),\"R\":\[+("\w+\s?\w+\s?\w+\s?\w+")/)
```

The string that doesn't seem to be captured is below:

```
if (typeof typeaheadResult !== "undefined") { typeaheadResult({"Q":"crapshoot","R":[]}) }
```

My regex doesn't work for the above string and I don't think it's because of the inappropriate word used.
Here is the rubular permalink to what I tried: http://rubular.com/r/WOr7xYPePs
It has the rest of the sample strings which are important.

Comment: so you want to match the `if (typeof typeaheadResult !== "undefined")` part? Because you regex matches something that starts with `typeaheadResult({`, so there's not way to match the entire string.

Comment: when you say "it doesn't work" for the above string, do you mean it doesn't match, or it matches but returns something unexpected in the matched groups?

Comment: I'd try [`typeaheadResult\({"Q":("[\w\s]*"),"R":\[+("[\w\s]*"|[^]]*)`](http://rubular.com/r/aKBiI0lOm4) to match either a double quoted string after `R` or any 0+ chars other than `]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it says `character class has ']' without escape`

Comment: just add the escape `[^\]]*`

Comment: Why do you have the OR `| [^]`? Why is the carrot needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part after `R:[` must contain at least 4 `\w` characters between `"`.

If it's intended to be optional, you have to add a `?`.

**Update**

Just adding a `?` at the end of your regex solves the problem: http://rubular.com/r/HUmtoffTmi

Comment: you beat me answering by about 30 seconds :)

Comment: What do you mean? It already has after `R:[ \w...` They are with plus signs because the word could be one or more letters.. see this: `"R\":\[+("\w+\s?\w+\s?\w+\s?\w+")`

Comment: I mean that your `regex` specifies there must be something between quotes after the `R:[` part. The string in your example doesn't contain it, so it doesn't match. If you add a `?` after the `)`, the whole group becomes optional, and the string will match.

Comment: I said there must be at least 4 characters because there are 4 `\w+` parts. `abcd` will match (each letter will match a`\w+`), but `abc` won't (there will remain one unmatched `\w+`).

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that there is at most one match per paragraph, and for there to be a match in a given paragraph, either `"[]"` follows `"R:` or the string following `"Q":"` and ending with the character preceding the next double quote begins with the string following `"R":[["` and ending with the character preceding the next double quote.

```
str =<<BITTER_END
\if (typeof typeaheadResult !== "undefined") { typeaheadResult({"Q":"standing desk Mike","R":[["standing desk",[["Home",4044]]],"standing desk converter","adjustable standing desk","standing desk 48","tabletop standing desk","glass standing desk desk"]}) }

if (typeof typeaheadResult !== "undefined") { typeaheadResult({"Q":"laptop bag","R":[["laptop bag",[["Electronics",3944]]],"laptop bags for 15.6 inch laptops","laptop bags for women","laptop bag 15.6","laptop bags for 17.3 in laptops","rolling laptop bag","laptop bag with wheels","laptop bag 17\""]}) }

\if (typeof typeaheadResult !== "undefined") { typeaheadResult({"Q":"sitting desk Melba","R":[["standing desk",[["Home",4044]]],"standing desk converter","adjustable standing desk","standing desk 48","tabletop standing desk","glass standing desk desk"]}) }

if (typeof typeaheadResult !== "undefined") { typeaheadResult({"Q":"crapshoot hello","R":[]}) }
BITTER_END
```

```
r = /
    typeaheadResult\(\{\"Q\":\" # match 'typeaheadResult({"Q":"'
    ([[[:alnum:]]\s]+)   # match letters, digits and spaces in capture group 1
    \",\"R\":            # match string
    (?:                  # begin non-capture group
      \[\[\"             # match 2 left brackets and a double quote
      ([[[:alnum:]]\s]+) # match > 0 letters, digits and spaces in capture group 2
      |                  # or
      (\[\])             # match left then right bracket in capture group 3
    )                    # end non-capture group
    /x                   # free-spacing regex definition mode

str.split(/\n\n+/).map do |s|
  ss = s[r]
  ss = nil unless (($2 && $1 =~ /\A#{$2}/) || $3=="[]")
  ss
end.compact
  #=> ["typeaheadResult({\"Q\":\"standing desk Mike\",\"R\":[[\"standing desk",
  #    "typeaheadResult({\"Q\":\"laptop bag\",\"R\":[[\"laptop bag",
  #    "typeaheadResult({\"Q\":\"crapshoot hello\",\"R\":[]"]
```

You might consider flagging possible bad data if `$2` is not `nil` and `$1.begins_with($2)` is `false`.